# Моё приложение на андроид студио скачивается только через USB

Tags: android

Я новичок в андроид студио на котлин и каждый раз когда я делаю приложение и пытаюсь его скачать не через USB кабель с ноута на телефон то оно не устанавливается, пробовал с трёх устройств

Comment: Конкретнее проблему опишите. "не устанавливается" - это может быть от "не могу найти файл для установки" до "установилось но не запускается".

Comment: Включен ли режим разработчика на телефоне ? Отладка по USB, Установка по USB ?

Comment: Если вы пытаетесь установить APK, который создан при запуске кнопкой пуск в студии - то он не установится другим способом, потому что не предназначен для распространения. Нажмите молоток и после билда ищите APK в `app/build/outputs/...`

Answer (score 0):

Нужно создать apk-файл специально из среды разработки. Его можно будет устанавливать на различные устройства. Можно создать подписанный своей цифровой подписью APK, а можно обычный. В Play Market потом можно обновлять свои приложения, подтверждая их цифровой подписью. Для создания обычного APK достаточно найти пункт "Build Bundle(s)/APK(s)" и нажать Build APK(s).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем, после создания apk-файла, среда разработки высветит диалоговое окошко, где нужно нажать "locate" - тогда откроется папка, где был создан apk-файл. Вот его уже можно будет устанавливать на различные устройства.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же вы хотите создать подписанный APK-файл, в среде разработки найдите такой пункт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше нужно будет создать хранилище ключей формата jks, задать пароль ему и новому ключу. Это делается в пару кликов с помощью среды разработки. Хранилище ключей нужно для цифровой подписи приложения, мол, вы разработчик, и имеете право загружать изменения к этому приложению.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]